# Comparador de igualdade estrita (===) dá resultados diferentes em PHP e em JavaScript, mesmo que os valores numéricos sejam iguais

Tags: php, javascript, característica-linguagem, tipagem, operadores

Em PHP o operador `===` faz a comparação do valor e do tipo, assim como outras linguagens. Porém eu me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```php
<?php
$var_1 = 8.0;
$var_2 = 4;
$calculo_1 = $var_1 / $var_2;

$var_3 = 10;
$var_2 = 5;
$calculo_2 = $var_3 / $var_2;

echo "calculo 1 = $calculo_1\n";
echo "calculo 2 = $calculo_2\n";

if ($calculo_1 === $calculo_2) {
    echo "iguais";
} else {
    echo "diferentes";
}
```

A saída deste código é:

```
calculo 1 = 2
calculo 2 = 2
diferentes
```

Ou seja, o operador `===` considerou que `$calculo_1` e `$calculo_2` são diferentes, mesmo com ambos tendo o mesmo valor.

Mas em JavaScript o comportamento não é o mesmo, e ele considera que os valores são iguais:

```js
let var_1 = 8.0;
let var_2 = 4;
let calculo_1 = var_1 / var_2;

let var_3 = 10;
var_2 = 5;
let calculo_2 = var_3 / var_2;

console.log(`calculo 1 = ${calculo_1}`);
console.log(`calculo 2 = ${calculo_2}`);

if (calculo_1 === calculo_2) {
    console.log("iguais");
} else {
    console.log("diferentes");
}
```

A saída é:

```
calculo 1 = 2
calculo 2 = 2
iguais
```

Ou seja, a comparação de igualdade estrita tem comportamentos diferentes nas duas linguagens, mesmo que os valores dos cálculos sejam os mesmos.

**Qual a explicação para o resultado ser falso em PHP e verdadeiro em JavaScript?**

Comment: Acho que as operações `var_2++` e `var_2--` acabavam "distraindo" e tirando o foco do problema central da pergunta, então tomei a liberdade de modificar os códigos para focar somente na questão principal: o fato do operador `===` se comportar diferente em cada uma das linguagens (mesmo que o valor numérico seja igual).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As linguagens tem maneiras diferentes de lidar com os tipos dos dados. Diga-se de passagem são justamente as duas linguagens populares que erraram feio nisto. E esse erro é o que faz as duas serem mal faladas (tem outros mas esse é o mais importante).

O operador `===` significa que os valores devem ser idênticos, ou seja, até o tipo do objeto deve ser o mesmo que o outro. Isso difere do `==` que basta o valor ser igual, o tipo pode ser diferente.

Em JavaScript o tipo numérico básico é sempre `Number`. Pode mandar imprimir com `typeof` para ver. Então se o valor é igual, o tipo também é, e tudo é idêntico.

```js
let var_1 = 8.0;
let var_2 = 4;
let calculo_1 = var_1 / var_2;
let var_3 = 10;
var_2 = 5;
let calculo_2 = var_3 / var_2;
console.log(`calculo_1 => ${typeof calculo_1}`);
console.log(`calculo_2 => ${typeof calculo_2}`);
console.log(`Identical => ${calculo_1 === calculo_2}`);
console.log(`Equal => ${calculo_1 == calculo_2}`);
```

Em PHP os tipos numéricos parecem os mesmos mas eles são diferentes. Mande imprimir o tipo de cada objeto para ver. Fiz aqui para mostrar:

```
$var_1 = 8.0;
$var_2 = 4;
$var_3 = 10;
$calculo_1 = $var_1 / $var_2++;
$calculo_2 = $var_3 / $var_2++;
echo "var_1 => " . gettype($var_1) . "\n";
echo "var_2 => " . gettype($var_2) . "\n";
echo "var_3 => " . gettype($var_3) . "\n";
echo "calculo_1 => " . gettype($calculo_1) . "\n";
echo "calculo_2 => " . gettype($calculo_2) . "\n";
echo "identical => " . ($calculo_1 === $calculo_2) . "\n";
echo "equal => " . ($calculo_1 == $calculo_2) . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kQny8P). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/hokxxlflcx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Numerics.php).

Dá para ver aí que um é `double` e o outro é `integer`. Então o valor é igual mas o tipo não, portanto eles não são idênticos, apenas o `==` dá `true`, ou mais precisamente `1`. Com o `===` dá nada, que é o falso do PHP, que é outra confusão da linguagem.

Comment: No caso o valor que foi armazenado na $calculo_1 foi armazenada como double, porque foi calculado um número double com um número integer. E na $calculo_2, o resultado como integer, pois o calculo foi feito por dois números inteiros. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por que você diz que JavaScript errou feio na maneira de lidar com dados?

Comment: @rodorgas eu não disse isso. Dê uma pesquisada aqui mesmo que tem várias respostas sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 7):

O problema é que, no código PHP, você está utilizando com dois tipos de dados diferentes – inteiros e *floats*. No JavaScript, só um tipo está sendo utilizado.

Repare o código PHP:

```
$var_1 = 8.0;
$var_2 = 4;
$var_3 = 10;
```

Os tipos são, respectivamente, `float`, `int` e `int`. Repare que o sufixo `.0` no primeiro literal faz com que a variável `$var_1` assuma o tipo `float`. No JavaScript, qualquer valor numérico<sup>1</sup>, independentemente de sua notação literal, é do tipo `number` (não há tal distinção porque internamente todo `number` é representado por um *float* de dupla precisão *per* IEEE 754).

Em PHP, quando uma operação aritmética é feita sendo *float* um dos operandos, o resultado também será *float*. Por conta disso, o tipo de `$calculo_1` *float* enquanto `$calculo_2` é do tipo  inteiro.

De fato, podemos confirmar isto:

```
> var_dump([$calculo_1, $calculo_2]);
< array(2) {
<   [0]=> float(2)
<   [1]=> int(2)
< }
```

E como você já deve saber, o operador `===` não retornará verdadeiro se os operandos tiverem tipos diferentes.

---

<sup>1: Só para não deixar informação faltando, no JavaScript existe também o tipo numérico `bigint`, denotado com sufixo literal `n`, mas não vem ao caso desta resposta. Nesse caso, sim, tratam-se de tipos numéricos diferentes em JS, mas que são totalmente incompatíveis — uma operação que mistura os dois lança um `TypeError`.</sup>